# Add allowed file extension

Tags: typo3

[image: Screenshot]

Hey dear friends. I need yours help again. I was created extension. So user can upload video. When I try to update this I get error:

1: Attempt to modify record 'small_01.mp4' (sys_file_reference:17) without permission. Or non-existing page.

I guess I have to add video extension to allowed. Tell me please how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the general allowed file type for images, change `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']` in your global configuration.

If you want to change the allowed file type in an extension for your own TCA fields you can do the following:

Since TYPO3 v12, the new type "file" should be used:

```
'columns' => [
    'image' => [
        'label' => 'My image',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'file',
            'maxitems' => 6,
            'allowed' => ['jpg','png','svg'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Documenation:

- migrate https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/Tca.html
- [TCA type "file"](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/File/Index.html) (since TYPO3 v12)
- [allowed file types for type "file"](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/File/Properties/Allowed.html) (since TYPO3 v12)

TYPO3 before v12:

```
'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
    'video', [], 'mp4' 
 ),
```

Comment: Please format answer as code and add an explanation.

Comment: Please note that getFileFieldTCAConfig is deprecated and should be migrated: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/Tca.html#migration-from-extensionmanagementutility-getfilefieldtcaconfig

Answer (score 0):

I think you have take field type "image" for your field, instead of "file".may it will work field type "file"